# Tensorflow loading variables in another graph

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way to somehow update the shape of input in tensor flow, I suppose no right? Actually I have trained my CNN and I wanted to reuse the trained convolution filters for different problem which involves the input of larger size. I tried creating a new graph, whose input placeholders are of different size but tensor-flow didn't let me load the trained parameters from other graph. What would be best way to cope with this problem.

Best Regards

Comment: I think you can get only cnn's weight and bias then save those as a numpy array. When you use the same cnn filter on the other graph, load them as initial values.

Comment: yeah This was only solution that I had in mind,

Comment: Why not create new placeholder in the same graph?